# loading xml data into Ultragrid

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am trying to show xml data in an Ultragrid.  I have tried using Ultragrid.loadfromxml and using the location of the file and i have also used a file input stream and throw that into the load xml method.  any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you can load an XML file with something like this

```
Dim dt as DataTable = new DataTable("myData")
dt.ReadXml("path_to_your_file")
ultraGrid1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

The UltraGrid can bind to anything that implements IList so you will need to load the data into a list of some kind.  If you need the grid to respond to changes to the collection after the initial load of the data then you would want to use an IBindingList.  There are more details on what the DataSource can be set to in the online help:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~DataSource.html

If you XML is in a format that can be read into a DataTable then the simplest solution is to bind the UltraGrid to a DataTable after calling ReadXml to load the data into the DataTable.

If you aren't able to use a DataTable, then you could use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098) to get the data and convert it to something that the UltraGrid can bind to.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the Infragistics Ultragrid Ninja, Mike Saltzman, himself:

> [The grid needs some sort of data source that implements either IList or IBindingList. So you would have to load your XML into an object of one of those types.](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/12271.aspx)

So you'll need to load your XML into some collection type that implements one of those interfaces and then set that as the data source on the grid. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431255/retrieving-data-from-xml-file) for how to load XML from a file. Then it's as simple as ...

```
UltraGrid1.DataSource = myAwesomeBindingListMadeFromXML
```

The [LoadFromXML](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout~LoadFromXml%28String,PropertyCategories%29.html) method on the UltraGrid.DisplayLayout that it designed for loaded a previously saved off layout (i.e. display settings), not the data in the grid itself.